# Correct use of Aria role and labels

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm building a site, and I'm a little unsure of the correct Aria label/roles to use. I've attached a mockup screenshot. I have a main header at the top of the page marked in green and off-page navigation (the trigger area in red). The header is in a `<header>` tag; inside that, I have a `<nav>` that is fixed to the left of the screen. Inside the fixed `<nav>`, I have another `<nav>` (with all the links) that is set to `aria-hidden="true"` (changing to false on open) & `aria-label="Primary navigation"`. The smaller navigation that is in the top right is also set to `<nav>` with `aria-label="Secondary navigation"`.

I'm unsure about the onscreen `<nav>` with the burger menu trigger. Should this be a nav? and would this be classed as the primary nav?

Is this the correct way to set this up?

[image]

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <button class="toggle-overlay">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="middle"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
    </button>
    
    <nav class="navigation" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Primary navigation">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services/">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/news/">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="/partners/">Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="/">Logo here</a>
  </div>
  
  <nav aria-label="Secondary navigation">Other nav</nav>
</header>
```